React Vite build error: Not bundling assets properly
I'm encountering an issue with the React Vite build process in my project. When attempting to build my React application using Vite, I'm facing difficulties with bundling certain assets. Despite trying various troubleshooting steps, I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Error Message:
❯ npm run build

> client@0.0.0 build
> vite build

vite v5.2.9 building for production...
<script src="./src/assets/dist/js/demo-theme.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/jsvectormap/dist/js/jsvectormap.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/jsvectormap/dist/maps/world.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/jsvectormap/dist/maps/world-merc.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/js/transliteration-input.bundle.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/js/transliteration-input.bundle1.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/js/tabler.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/js/demo.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/fullcalendar/core/main.min.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/fullcalendar/daygrid/main.min.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/fullcalendar/interaction/main.min.js"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/nouislider/dist/nouislider.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/litepicker/dist/litepicker.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
<script src="./src/assets/dist/libs/tom-select/dist/js/tom-select.base.min.js?1692870487"> in "/index.html" can't be bundled without type="module" attribute
transforming (1) index.html
../img/flags/ams.svg referenced in /Users/mrperfect/Work/Project/Thaali-System/Client/src/assets/dist/css/tabler-flags.min.css?1692870487 didn't resolve at build time, it will remain unchanged to be resolved at runtime
✓ 196 modules transformed.
dist/index.html                                 2.86 kB │ gzip:   0.87 kB
dist/assets/ms-CZkjZzGU.svg                     4.12 kB │ gzip:   1.45 kB
dist/assets/clickandbuy-dark-CGBIBCkt.svg       4.21 kB │ gzip:   1.53 kB
dist/assets/clickandbuy-tmVVmM-n.svg            4.27 kB │ gzip:   1.54 kB
dist/assets/fk-_QlCwVIX.svg                     4.33 kB │ gzip:   1.61 kB
dist/assets/nu-BQEHb6vi.svg                     4.43 kB │ gzip:   1.46 kB
dist/assets/zm-DVZbRbRA.svg                     4.47 kB │ gzip:   1.91 kB
dist/assets/mp-CBwCHmJz.svg                     4.54 kB │ gzip:   1.93 kB
dist/assets/cirrus-DJU8hf7M.svg                 4.60 kB │ gzip:   1.83 kB
dist/assets/cirrus-dark-C_FZ3YOh.svg            4.60 kB │ gzip:   1.83 kB
dist/assets/payoneer-dark-8SdVItfA.svg          4.67 kB │ gzip:   2.26 kB
dist/assets/ukash-dark-FvZmcID8.svg             4.67 kB │ gzip:   2.31 kB
dist/assets/payoneer-Brx-SZq1.svg               4.67 kB │ gzip:   2.27 kB
dist/assets/ukash-RFnnpxAy.svg                  4.67 kB │ gzip:   2.32 kB
dist/assets/paysafecard-dark-BKM4s1QQ.svg       4.92 kB │ gzip:   2.34 kB
dist/assets/paysafecard-DGt-fjDI.svg            4.92 kB │ gzip:   2.34 kB
dist/assets/er-DJBysoLd.svg                     4.97 kB │ gzip:   2.33 kB
dist/assets/maestro-DPsXXNX9.svg                4.97 kB │ gzip:   2.06 kB
dist/assets/maestro-dark-6gIPbnJX.svg           4.97 kB │ gzip:   2.06 kB
dist/assets/unionpay-dark-8dv3KInM.svg          5.12 kB │ gzip:   2.54 kB
dist/assets/unionpay-CodtPvg-.svg               5.13 kB │ gzip:   2.49 kB
dist/assets/googlewallet-dark-DXVkweVi.svg      5.18 kB │ gzip:   2.32 kB
dist/assets/googlewallet-D3gNTfBW.svg           5.37 kB │ gzip:   2.44 kB
dist/assets/lk-AWfD8liu.svg                     5.47 kB │ gzip:   2.41 kB
dist/assets/vi-B4jqVt9E.svg                     5.50 kB │ gzip:   2.35 kB
dist/assets/eway-dark-DxPgLJvm.svg              5.52 kB │ gzip:   2.65 kB
dist/assets/eway-DSjUhOrL.svg                   5.53 kB │ gzip:   2.65 kB
dist/assets/gb-wls-CLK0htuw.svg                 5.73 kB │ gzip:   2.64 kB
dist/assets/me-D4jd8pqB.svg                     5.74 kB │ gzip:   2.31 kB
dist/assets/gu-EGLN7gjB.svg                     5.81 kB │ gzip:   1.89 kB
dist/assets/hr-BY0h0Y6m.svg                     5.93 kB │ gzip:   2.22 kB
dist/assets/bancontact-DbpvtM6K.svg             6.00 kB │ gzip:   2.34 kB
dist/assets/bancontact-dark-7zOrRiDh.svg        6.01 kB │ gzip:   2.34 kB
dist/assets/worldpay-dark-BnpraBPY.svg          6.26 kB │ gzip:   2.90 kB
dist/assets/worldpay-DyVQXA8n.svg               6.29 kB │ gzip:   2.91 kB
dist/assets/ad-BAKXjaEZ.svg                     6.30 kB │ gzip:   2.32 kB
dist/assets/fj-DUNYKJdm.svg                     6.47 kB │ gzip:   2.47 kB
dist/assets/al-BUHdMPlT.svg                     6.50 kB │ gzip:   2.92 kB
dist/assets/mastercard-dark-IWbYQztW.svg        6.90 kB │ gzip:   2.78 kB
dist/assets/mastercard-xg2L5kbI.svg             6.90 kB │ gzip:   2.78 kB
dist/assets/epayco-dark-BOGvwzn9.svg            6.91 kB │ gzip:   3.23 kB
dist/assets/epayco-CAbKWIQW.svg                 6.91 kB │ gzip:   3.23 kB
dist/assets/nf-C_bJu4FR.svg                     6.99 kB │ gzip:   3.08 kB
dist/assets/va-CmeiX4sx.svg                     7.05 kB │ gzip:   2.57 kB
dist/assets/sh-NZtq-mf5.svg                     7.35 kB │ gzip:   2.46 kB
dist/assets/pn-DVfAUlrv.svg                     7.76 kB │ gzip:   3.02 kB
dist/assets/bitcoin-dark-AmiA6OMf.svg           8.06 kB │ gzip:   3.53 kB
dist/assets/bitcoin-BRONVgFM.svg                8.09 kB │ gzip:   3.54 kB
dist/assets/verisign-dark-pRnvMd65.svg          8.45 kB │ gzip:   3.24 kB
dist/assets/verisign-UJSsM8wZ.svg               8.46 kB │ gzip:   3.25 kB
dist/assets/bn-C8pQTTq_.svg                     8.70 kB │ gzip:   3.71 kB
dist/assets/ky-CKxwvqq0.svg                     8.88 kB │ gzip:   2.69 kB
dist/assets/gp-DH52Emsp.svg                     9.26 kB │ gzip:   3.39 kB
dist/assets/gs-BL_GSanl.svg                     9.83 kB │ gzip:   4.14 kB
dist/assets/pt-CSP5CmhO.svg                    10.17 kB │ gzip:   2.27 kB
dist/assets/sepa-DsKP7rot.svg                  10.47 kB │ gzip:   4.38 kB
dist/assets/sepa-dark-D9mKwlTL.svg             10.47 kB │ gzip:   4.38 kB
dist/assets/afrun-BesbE1XM.svg                 11.84 kB │ gzip:   4.59 kB
dist/assets/es-QLO7BHGo.svg                    12.11 kB │ gzip:   3.94 kB
dist/assets/io-Ptko5M5Z.svg                    12.63 kB │ gzip:   3.57 kB
dist/assets/pe-Cql2yJ_Z.svg                    14.25 kB │ gzip:   4.07 kB
dist/assets/kz-BmV29Mbl.svg                    14.33 kB │ gzip:   4.99 kB
dist/assets/vg-B7c2hEsH.svg                    14.49 kB │ gzip:   4.06 kB
dist/assets/jcb-dark-rwiJKBGd.svg              17.86 kB │ gzip:   4.39 kB
dist/assets/jcb-B6GBrLzb.svg                   17.93 kB │ gzip:   4.41 kB
dist/assets/sm-B6FYPIkT.svg                    18.37 kB │ gzip:   6.74 kB
dist/assets/tm-2J4dcJU8.svg                    18.73 kB │ gzip:   5.42 kB
dist/assets/rs-DYJElTPt.svg                    19.27 kB │ gzip:   6.30 kB
dist/assets/dinersclub-dark-2AktZXr2.svg       22.69 kB │ gzip:   8.76 kB
dist/assets/dinersclub-CwLBpsqO.svg            22.73 kB │ gzip:   8.77 kB
dist/assets/primeicons-DsZ1W7-Z.woff2          30.18 kB
dist/assets/kh-DjN1I8Sz.svg                    45.70 kB │ gzip:  14.72 kB
dist/assets/pm-Ct4bFgT1.svg                    70.06 kB │ gzip:  23.91 kB
dist/assets/primeicons-NDVQFXzF.ttf            72.20 kB
dist/assets/primeicons-CCFeZR6K.woff           72.28 kB
dist/assets/primeicons-Dk_eWBPK.eot            72.38 kB
dist/assets/logo-BC9cu9tX.svg                  80.63 kB │ gzip:  19.85 kB
dist/assets/logo-small-square-yOGm5WoB.ico     90.10 kB
dist/assets/sa-C0z8fl8-.svg                   103.80 kB │ gzip:  38.38 kB
dist/assets/primeicons-BubJZjaf.svg           291.45 kB │ gzip:  90.72 kB
dist/assets/index-OuyipUlU.css              1,686.62 kB │ gzip: 245.55 kB
dist/assets/index-D962Vjir.js                 824.91 kB │ gzip: 199.54 kB

(!) Some chunks are larger than 500 kB after minification. Consider:
- Using dynamic import() to code-split the application
- Use build.rollupOptions.output.manualChunks to improve chunking: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-manualchunks
- Adjust chunk size limit for this warning via build.chunkSizeWarningLimit.
✓ built in 1.22s


Checked for any syntax errors in my code.
Updated all dependencies to their latest versions.
Searched online for similar issues, but couldn't find a solution that worked for my specific case.

